# How to check if an external command exists in Lua

Tags: neovim, lua

How do I translate this VimL code into Lua?

```
if executable('rg')
  set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
endif
```

Comment: Really, you want to translate it into Lua uses NeoVim's Lua APIs; for that, you probably just want to go through their relevant `:help` pages to learn how to set options or test `executable()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer below assumes you are running neovim and not vim.

`:h vim.cmd()` lets you execute a vimscript command from lua. It takes the command as a string. So you can wrap any vimscript in a string and pass it to `:lua vim.cmd()` and it should work.

```
vim.cmd[[
if executable('rg')
  set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
endif
]]
```

On the other hand, if you want a more lua-like approach, you can use `:h vim.fn` to call any vim function, both user-defined and built-in. With `:h vim.o` or `:h vim.opt` you can set the vim options.

```
if vim.fn.executable('rg') == 1 then
  vim.o.grepprg = 'rg --vimgrep'
end
```

Comment: I understand your post suggest two different ways. Maybe could you make it more explicite.